# Retrieve unique values from column based on value from other column

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures

I have a table like this

```
symbol    length    id
A         10        id_1
A         15        id_2
A         15        id_3
B         20        id_4
B         25        id_5
...       ...       ...
```

I want to print the following in a new table

```
symbol    length    id
A         15        id_2; id_3
B         25        id_5
...       ...       ...
```

So I want to loop through the `symbol` column. When there are duplicate values in this column, I want to print the line where the numeric length-value is the greatest (example: symbol B). When the greatest `length` values are equal, I want to merge the values in the `id`column (example: symbol A) and print this new line.

How should I do this in perl?

Comment: Is the table sorted as in the example?

Comment: yes, based on symbol and then on length

Answer (score 2):

The tool in perl for coalescing duplicates is a hash. Hashes are key-value pairs, but the useful part is - the value can be an array (reference).

I'd be suggesting something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %length_of;
my %ids_of;

my $heading_row = <DATA>;
while (<DATA>) {
    my ( $symbol, $length, $id ) = split;
    if ( not defined $length_of{$symbol} or $length_of{$symbol} < $length ) {
        $length_of{$symbol} = $length;
    }
    push( @{ $ids_of{$symbol}{$length} }, $id );
}

print join( "\t", "symbol", "length", "ids" ), "\n";
foreach my $symbol ( sort keys %ids_of ) {
    my $length = $length_of{$symbol};
    print join( "\t",
        $symbol, 
        $length,
        join( "; ", @{ $ids_of{$symbol}{$length} } ) ),
        "\n";
}

__DATA__
symbol    length    id
A         10        id_1
A         15        id_2
A         15        id_3
B         20        id_4
B         25        id_5
```

What this is doing is - iterating your data, and saving the highest `length` value (in `%length_of`).  It's also stashing each of the ids - by symbol and length (in `%ids_of`). It keeps them all, so this might not be very efficient if you've a lot of data.

Comment: my table has 36000 rows

Comment: Depends more on filesize - it'll retain most of it in memory, and add an overhead because that's how it works. 36000 rows of 10 bytes or so isn't anything to worry about.

Answer (score 2):

Just remember the last symbol and length and accumulate the ids:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my ($last_l, $last_s, @i);

sub out {
    print "$last_s\t$last_l\t", join(";", @i), "\n"
}

while (<>) {
    my ($s, $l, $i) = split;
    out() if $last_s and $s ne $last_s;
    undef @i if $last_l < $l;
    push @i, $i;
    $last_s = $s;
    $last_l = $l;
}
out();
```

Answer (score 0):

This approach builds a [hash of hashes of arrays](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) by using the values from the `symbol` and `length` columns as keys and adding the values from the `id` column as array references. For the simple dataset you provided such a complex data structure is not really needed, but the approach shown below might be more flexible in cases where data is not sorted.

I use the `max` function from ([`List::Util`](http://www.metacpan.org/pod/List::Util) , which is part of the core distribution) to get the maximum `length` value for each `symbol`, and `Data::Dumper` to help visualize things.

```
use Data::Dumper ;
use List::Util 'max';
use v5.16; 

my (%hash, @lines) ;

while ( <DATA>) {
    chomp ;
    next if $. == 1 ;
    push @lines,  [ split ] ;
}

for (@lines) { 
    push @{ $hash{ $_->[0] }{ $_->[1] } }, $_->[2] ;
}

say "This is your %hash:\n", Dumper \%hash; 

for my $symbol ( keys %hash ) {
    my $max =  max ( keys $hash{$symbol} ) ;
    say "$symbol \t",  "$max \t",  join "; ", @{ $hash{$symbol}{$max} };
}

__DATA__
symbol    length    id
A         10        id_1
A         15        id_2
A         15        id_3
B         20        id_4
B         25        id_5
```

**Output**:

```
This is your %hash:
$VAR1 = {
          'A' => {
                   '10' => [
                             'id_1'
                           ],
                   '15' => [
                             'id_2',
                             'id_3'
                           ]
                 },
          'B' => {
                   '25' => [
                             'id_5'
                           ],
                   '20' => [
                             'id_4'
                           ]
                 }
        };

A       15      id_2; id_3
B       25      id_5
```